# Assets cannot be found

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Before xCode 9, when I wanted to create a UIImageView with an image, I would drag an image into the project side bar and create a UIImage with the name of that file. This worked and all was well.

However, with Xcode 9 this will not work. It won't be able to find that file, even though it's there in the main bundle. What I needed to do was to put the image into the Assets folder, and then it was able to find the image and show it in the UIImageView.

Likewise, when working with Sprite Kit, I would create a folder in my desktop with a .atlas extension, drag all my images into that, and then drag the .atlas folder in the project. Then I'd create a SKTextureAtlas with the name of the .atlas folder, and it worked. With Xcode 9 however, this again did not work. I would get a 'Texture Atlas 'foo' cannot be found' message in the console. So I went to the Assets folder, clicked the add icon and choose New Sprite Atlas, renamed that folder, and dragged my images into it. Now creating the texture atlas with that name worked.

What I'm now trying to do, and having trouble with, is creating an SKVideoNode using init(filedNamed: "foo.mov"), and as you guessed, this no longer works if you dragged the file into the project's side bar. So I thought maybe I again need to somehow do this through the Assets folder. I found that when I add my .mov file to the Assets folder, it gets created as a 'Data' type ('Data' shows in the top right corner of its box in the Assets folder). What I can do now is this:

```
let d = NSDataAsset(name: "foo") // 'foo' is the .mov file in Assets
d.data // the underlying content
```

Turns out d is not nil, which was good news, but the only way to access the underlying content is just by way of .data, and you cannot create an SKVideoNode with data. I also wanted to load a sound file, which I used to do like this:

```
let a = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("bar.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)
```

But I get the message 'Error loading sound resource: "bar.mp3"'.

Comment: ... loading images not in bundle from project sidebar still works in Xcode 9, you may have a bad update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check to see if your resources are being bundled.

Go into your project settings and click on the Build Phases tab,  make sure your resources are in the copy bundle resources section
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot KnightOfDragon!! This thing was baffling me. You were right; none of the assets were in the Copy Bundle Resources section..even though when adding them I selected 'copy if needed' and 'add to target'. Do you think I should reinstall Xcode since dragged in assets aren't getting automatically added to the bundle for me?

Comment: no, I noticed the assets did not go into the copy section, they must have changed that part of it.  The sidebar should still work though

Comment: Ah I see. So when I drag a resource into the project side bar, i shouldn't need to manually add it to the bundle then? Cuz for me, even the sidebar resources cannot be found unless I explicitly go to Copy Bundle Resources and add them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but my issue was I did not select "Create groups" when dragging a folder of sounds into XCode.   That plus the "Copy items if needed" worked for me.